# Is it possible to create an AWS Private Link for resources in multiple AWS accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have my RDS instances on one AWS account and I have set up my application on Kubernetes Cluster on another account. I need the application to talk to RDS instances on another account. I chose VPC Endpoint(Private Link) to achieve the same, so that the RDS data is safe and secure. Is it possible to have a Private Link established between multiple AWS accounts. Both the accounts are under the same AWS organization.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have a Private Link established between multiple AWS accounts.

Yes. The AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/endpoint-service.html) explains that a service consumer can be a different account:

> Grant permissions to specific service consumers (**AWS accounts**, IAM users, and IAM roles) to create a **connection** to your endpoint service.

Setting up permissions for other accounts to your Private Link service is explained in:

- [Adding and removing permissions for your endpoint service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/add-endpoint-service-permissions.html)

Comment: Thanks. Just adding to this question. How to set up a NLB for an RDS instance? I am able to setup only for the available EC2 instance.

Comment: @sriramsm04 Hi. No problem. I think you would need to have an instance which would expose api to the rds. So the workflow would be: NLB->EC2->RDS.

Comment: I think this answer is somewhat incomplete... while PrivateLink says it supports cross-account access, some service-specific implementations like API Gateway don't currently support it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-vpclink.html#:~:text=The%20network%20load%20balancer%20must%20be%20owned%20by%20the%20same%20AWS%20account%20of%20the%20API%20owner

Answer (score -1):

I think the better architecture would be to use **VPC Peering** to connect the VPC with the database to the VPC with the Kubernetes cluster.

The data remains "safe and secure" because it stays within the two VPCs.

No Network Load Balancer would be required.